# Why do I get "setTimeout is not a function" here?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am making a simple memory game. I used some setTimeout. Until a point, It was going good. After that I wanted to add a stopwatch. And bom. I got this error.

> `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setTimeout' of object [object Object] is not a function`

At this line:

```
function counter(){

ctxCounter.font="100pt Arial";
var fillT= setTimeout( function(){ctxCounter.fillText("3",270,340);} , 100);
var clearT= setTimeout( function(){counterClear();} , 1000);  
}
```

and my stopWatch part's code. After adding this line I get the error written above. But without stopwatch everything works perfectly.

```
var timer=0;
var running=false;
    

    function startPause(){
        if(running==false){
            running=true;
            increment();
        }
        else running=false;             
    }

    function reset(){
        timer=0;
        running=false;
    }


    function increment(){
        if(running==true){
            
            window.setTimeout=(

                function(){
                var mins= Math.floor(timer/600);
                var secs= Math.floor(timer/10);
                var tenths= timer%1000;
                var all= mins+":"+secs+":"+tenths;
                console.log(all);
                increment();
                },100);
        }

    }
```

I've stuck here for two days. Please, helm me.

Comment: Change setTimeout=( to setTimeout(

Comment: I want to buy a car to you. How can't I see that. I'm hittin my head to closest wall. Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: I might be a little late at the party but for the sake of good, mistakes like this can be avoided by using a better javascript IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) nowadays. It will save you decades of scratching your head.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
window.setTimeout=( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot men. If I have more reputation, I would vote up :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug at the `increment` function, there was a `=` after `window.setTimeout`

```
function increment(){
    if(running==true){

        window.setTimeout(

            function(){
            var mins= Math.floor(timer/600);
            var secs= Math.floor(timer/10);
            var tenths= timer%1000;
            var all= mins+":"+secs+":"+tenths;
            console.log(all);
            increment();
            },100);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just fixed it. Sorry for this stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) is normally a function, not a variable. You're reassigning it to the value 100 in your statement;

```
window.setTimeout=(function(){...}, 100);
```

Next time you try to call it, it's not a function anymore.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. I used setTimeout 20 times maybe. But this one I could't see.